# How long was the main quartet in the "Good Place?"

Tags: the-good-place

In the heaven-based comedy *The Good Place*, we find out that

> the main quartet of Eleanor, Chidi, Tahani, and Jason were in the Bad Place the whole time.

After this realization, the world is reset. However, this secret is found out again. And again. And again. It turns out that the world was reset over two hundred times. How much total time did the main group spend in the "Good Place?" I knew that their longest run was six months and their shortest run was a few seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

250-300 years, according to series creator Michael Schur:

> We figured that the events of S1 took somewhere around four months of “time.” (Michael then reboots them 801 more times, the longest lasting 11 months and the shortest being 8 seconds…we calculated that the median length was probably in that 4-month range, so the total length of all of the reboots is somewhere around 250-300 years.)

Source is an interview from October 2017: [‘The Good Place’ Creator Michael Schur Explains The Show’s New Twist](http://uproxx.com/sepinwall/the-good-place-twist-mike-schur-interview-team-cockroach-recap/3/)

Comment: I guess he doesn't understand the difference between median and mean.